# Cannot see folder details after mounting s3 bucket

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, filesystems, ubuntu-server, s3fs

I've started using S3 to backup data from an EC2 instance running server (Ubuntu Server). I've managed get this working using [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon). Created the folder /mnt/s3 and I've mounted the bucket on that folder.
Everything seems to be working fine so far: I can see and change bucket content, mount and unmount it just fine, etc.
However I've noticed something kinda strange (for me at least) after mounting the bucket, "ls -la" on /mnt/ returned this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 2011-10-24 16:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 2011-07-07 18:17 ..
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?                ? s3
```

So I've been wondering what can cause this behaviour. Does anyone have an idea about what causes this?
Like I said, everything seems to be working, I'm just curious about this phenomenon and I'd like to know if I should be worried about it or not.

Btw, when I umount the bucket, the folder details become normal again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to see the sub-folders that were inside your S3 bucket under mnt/s3/?

Comment: Yes, after I mount the bucket I can see and access all the folders and files inside it.

Comment: @GiridharMurali

As I've said this is more an academical question since I've got no problems getting this to work properly.

I believe this can be something related with permissions/users since I've mounted the bucket using sudo (as root) but tried to see the details as a regular user. Because when I do "ls -la" as root I get this:

**drwxr-xr-x  1 root root    0 1970-01-01 01:00**

I found this strange since it seems to be a folder with empty info, but I also get size 0 on every folder inside the bucket.. so this is probably a common behaviour on this situations.

Comment: I'm sorry, the reason I asked if you were able to see the sub-folders was because I am trying the same and I am not able to see the sub-folders. Any hints on how to get the sub-folders to show?

Comment: Now that I think of it.. I had problems when I created the folders first with the AWS web console for S3. When I did it like that, after I mounted the bucket I could not access some of the folders created (or all of them probably, I don't remember exactly).
At the time since I was testing this what I did was delete all folders I've created using the AWS web interface.. mounted the (empty) bucket on my filesystem, entered it and created the folders I needed on the command line using "mkdir".
I don't know if this can also be the problem you're having or not...

Answer (score 1):

sudo s3fs -o allow_other BUcket_Name   /mnt(where you want to mount)